# Does MIMIC-III have patients with atrial fibrillation & knee osteoarthritis?

Tags: mimic-iii

Do you know if the MIMIC-III database includes patients (in parcticular their free-text notes, medications & demography) - that have either atrial fibrillation,  knee osteoarthritis or closely related diseases?

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly there are patients with atrial fibrillation:

```
select value, count(distinct icustay_id) as numad
from chartevents
where itemid = 212
group by value
order by numpat desc;

   value         | numadm
-----------------+--------
Normal Sinus     |  24787
Sinus Tachy      |  15481
Sinus Brady      |   7512
Atrial Fib       |   5416
```

In terms of osteoarthritis, one can check the ICD-9 codes that were used to bill for the patient's hospital stay. Looking for patients with ICD-9 code 715 (Osteoarthrosis and allied disorders) gives:

```
select count(distinct hadm_id) as numadm
from diagnoses_icd
where icd9_code between '715' and '71599';

 numadm 
--------
   1453
```

And isolating that to Osteoarthritis of the lower leg (which knee is classified under):

```
 select count(distinct hadm_id) as numadm
 from diagnoses_icd
 where icd9_code in ('71516','71526','71536','71596');

 numadm 
--------
   321
```